# SciKit-Learn: Error when predicting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

This seems to be a common error from what I've seen, but has a number of potential causes.

I'm trying to put together a logistic regression in Python. My data is saved as a pandas data frame.

```
train, test = train_test_split(final_dat[train_cols], train_size=0.80, random_state=1)
logit = sm.Logit(train['SPR_Created__c'], train.drop(['SPR_Created__c'], axis=1)) 
result = logit.fit()
print result.summary()
result.predict(test[train_cols])
```

The error:

```
result.predict(test[train_cols])

ValueError: shapes (13664,18) and (17,) not aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 17 (dim 0)
```

I'm not sure about this error occurence as all most variables have been adjusted.

```
final_dat[train_cols].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 68319 entries, 0 to 31978
Data columns (total 18 columns):
Is_Subject                                68319 non-null int64
Is_Description                            68319 non-null int64
SPR_Created__c                            68319 non-null int64
description2_contains_any_synonym         68319 non-null int64
description_length                        68319 non-null int64
subject_length                            68319 non-null int64
description2_length                       68319 non-null int64
Is_Description2                           68319 non-null int64
Is_Adverse_Event                          68319 non-null int64
subject_contains_common_spr_terms         68319 non-null int64
description_contains_common_spr_terms     68319 non-null int64
description2_contains_common_spr_terms    68319 non-null int64
pattern_exists_in_description             68319 non-null int64
pattern_exists_in_description_count       68319 non-null float64
pattern_exists_in_description2            68319 non-null int64
pattern_exists_in_description2_count      68319 non-null float64
subject_contains_any_synonym              68319 non-null int64
description_contains_any_synonym          68319 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(16)
memory usage: 12.4 MB
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you add your data ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to define the variables you use, or at least substitute the data with something similar, but I think I found your issue anyway.

When you perform the train test split, `train` and `test` are DataFrames with the columns being defined from `train_cols`. I assume that 'SPR_Created__c' must be included in `train_cols`.

What you are trying to do is predict using `test` with ALL of the columns, including your target column 'SPR_Created__c'. However, you want to be using all columns EXCEPT for 'SPR_Created__c'. Instead of doing `result.predict(test[train_cols])` (which is redundant anyway because those are the only columns in `test` already, so you can just use `test` instead of `test[train_cols]`) you want to do `result.predict(test.drop(['SPR_Created__c']))`.

That is the reason your shape is off by one, because you are training your model with all columns in `train_cols` except for 'SPR_Created__c' but you are testing your model with all of these columns.

TL;DR: `result.predict(test.drop(['SPR_Created__c']))` instead of `result.predict(test[train_cols])`